# ¿Porque cuando asigno un valor a un Objeto este lo marca como undefined cuando no es asi?

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de asignar un nuevo Key value a un Object pero cuando lo hago este me lo marca como undefined despues de que se lo asigno, a pesar de que en el HTML lo muestra sin problema no puedo manipularlo en en Typescript

Esta es la forma en que lo hago:

```
  obtenerEmpresas() {
    let arrNewEmpresa = [];
    this.empresaService.obtenerEmpresas().then((resp: any) => {
      console.warn(resp)
      let Arrempresa = resp.cont.empresasP;
      for (const item of Arrempresa) {
        if (item.blnActivo) {
          this.sectoresService.obtenerSectoresIdGiro(item.idGiro._id).then((sector: any) => {
            item.sector = sector.cont.strNombre;
            // Object.assign(item, { sector: sector.cont.strNombre })
            console.warn(item.sector)
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            //No hay empresas
          });
          this.vacantesService.obtieneVacantesByFilter(
            this.idEspacioTrabajo,
            this.idTipoSalario,
            this.idTipoContratacion,
            this.idCarrerra,
            this.created_at,
            this.nmbSueldoMin,
            this.nmbSueldoMax,
            this.blnActivo,
            this.dteInicioPublicacion,
            this.dteFinPublicacion,
            item._id)
            .then((vacantes: any) => {
              console.log(vacantes);
              // item["publicaciones"] = `${vacantes.cont.count}`;
              Object.assign(item, { publicaciones: vacantes.cont.count })

            }).catch((err) => {
              // item["publicaciones"] = `${err.error.cont.count}`;
              Object.assign(item, { publicaciones: err.error.cont.count })

            })
          arrNewEmpresa.push(item);
        }

      }
    }).catch((err: any) => {
      err.mesage
    }).then(() => {
      this.empresa = arrNewEmpresa;
      for (const iterator of this.empresa) {
        console.log(iterator.sector)
      }
    })
  }
```

Al querer manipularlo me marca como undefined en el for of que hago al final de la función.

Alguna solución a este problema?

Comment: La pregunta no parece proporcionar suficiente información. ¿Qué es lo que marca como undefined? ¿Podrías incluir el error que te da en tu pregunta?

Comment: antes de entrar al `for of` haz un `console.log(Arrempresa)` mira que tiene dentro, si recibes `undefined` al momento de hacer `Object.assign(item, { publicaciones: err.error.cont.count })` es por que el `item` puede ser `undefined` o por que  uno de estos atributos es `undefined` en el atributo `pulbicacion` `vacantes` o tal vez `cont`, si pasa por el `catch()` podría ocurrir el mismo error, concuerdo con @ArmandoHoyos puedes colocar el mensaje de la consola de cual es el error.

Comment: estas haciendo push a `arrNewEmpresa` sin que las promesas terminen, tienes que esperar el llamado a tus servicios y posteriormente hacer el push.